# Obvious reference block the publish of my .Net projet (AspnetCompileMerge)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dll

I have a huge problem since the migration from a webforms (.Net 4) project to a mixed ASP MVC / Webforms (.Net 4.6.1)

My project generate but can't be published.

I have that error : The copy of bin\System.Interactive.Async.dll to obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\System.Interactive.Async.dll failed.

If I find that file from the old project, and I copy it to the bin or if I reference it, and check "local copy", it will work for that file. But I'll have an eror on the next dll file.

Below an extract of the file needed, btw it hangs also if there is a xml file.

[image: file asked]

Some files are very obvious, for example, System.Collections.Concurrent.dll should be included in the .Net framework 4.0

I tryied to clean the project, delete obj / bin, create a new project and copy all the file, the problem remains.

Does someone has a solution, my only workaround is to copy all the previous dell and copy them in the bin folder before publishing.

Comment: Have you tried to close all tabs before publishing?

Comment: I'd also try to run VS as administrator, just in case there is a weird permissions problem

Comment: Already tryied to close all tabs, reboot computer, run as administrator, and also same problem on a second pc. I have the problem with .dll, .xml, .refresh file.

Comment: I don't know then what could be the problem. As a temporary workaround, you could use the before publish event to copy all the files from bin to obj...

Comment: well it's probably the best workaround Pikoh but it isn't funky :(